# Есть ли союз "либо... или"?

Tags: союзы

Работы для этих трех категорий должны быть созданы либо на основе изданий книг организатора OCABF или же на основе произведений, участвовавших в любом из трех OCABF.

союз либо... или возможен?

Может, только или... или

или

либо... либо

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то это повторяющийся союз, не думаю, что "либо... или " нормативен

Answer (score 2):

Вы знаете, некоторое время назад видел очень жаркое обсуждение. Сейчас попытался найти - не получилось. Поэтому перескажу под свою ответственность.  
К единому мнению там не пришли (вроде как есть случаи, когда такое построение выглядит меньшим из зол), но во фразах типа вашей нет никаких причин не использовать обычный повторяющийся союз. Причем с запятой, конечно.